# Parsing XML file using XMLHolder and then adding them to an arrayList

Tags: java, xml, groovy

**example.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <Element>
       <Language Type="Java">
            <parameter name="JavatPoint">
                <url>https://www.javatpoint.com/</url>
            </parameter>

            <parameter name="Guru99">
                <url>https://www.guru99.com/</url>
            </parameter> 

            <parameter name="w3schools">
                <url>https://www.w3schools.com/</url>
            </parameter> 
       </Language>

       <Language sdkType="Python">
            <parameter name="Tutorialspoint">
                <url>https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/</url>
            </parameter>

            <parameter name="LearnPython">
                <url>https://learnpythonthehardway.org/</url>
            </parameter> 

            <parameter name="Code Academy">
                <url>https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-python</url>
            </parameter>    
       </language> 
   </Element>
```

I need to parse this example.xml based on the Type(ex.java,python) to get the url value and add those values to an arrayList. As I am not aware of xmlHolder can anyone please guide me to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Please start from https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html .  There are examples there

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it fails. SO is no offshore coding service.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Groovy like this (please note the last  in your example is with a lower-case *L* and is not valid XML):

```
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper

def xmlString ='''

     <Element>
       <Language Type="Java">
            <parameter name="JavatPoint">
                <url>https://www.javatpoint.com/</url>
            </parameter>

            <parameter name="Guru99">
                <url>https://www.guru99.com/</url>
            </parameter> 

            <parameter name="w3schools">
                <url>https://www.w3schools.com/</url>
            </parameter> 
       </Language>

       <Language sdkType="Python">
            <parameter name="Tutorialspoint">
                <url>https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/</url>
            </parameter>

            <parameter name="LearnPython">
                <url>https://learnpythonthehardway.org/</url>
            </parameter> 

            <parameter name="Code Academy">
                <url>https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-python</url>
            </parameter>    
       </Language> 
   </Element>
''' 
// error in closing tag

def Element = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlString)
def arr = []
def a = Element.Language.each() { node ->
    node.attributes().each { att, lang ->
        println lang
        arr = []
        node.'**'.findAll() { childnode -> childnode.name() == 'parameter' }.url.each {
            arr.add(it)
        }
    }
    arr.each { println it }
}
```